# How to get minimum and maximum value from a `rangpicker` for price slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the minimum and maximum value at the end of the mouse-drag.

**Please refer the following code:**

```
    <div id="double_number_range" style="margin-top: 13px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        /*Price slider*/
        $("#double_number_range").rangepicker({
            type: "double",
            startValue: 0,
            endValue: 1000,
            translateSelectLabel: function(currentPosition, totalPosition) {
                return parseInt(1000 * (currentPosition / totalPosition));
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are rangepicker ? A plugin that you use ? If yes, which plugin is this ?

Comment: the plugin name is rangepicker and also above mentioned as function name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the answer....

```
$(document).on('mouseup', 'span.label.select-label:eq(0)', function(){
  alert('Maximum '+parseInt($(this).text(), 10));
});
$(document).on('mouseup', 'span.label.select-label:eq(1)', function(){
  alert('Minimum '+parseInt($(this).text(), 10));
});
```

Thanks for your response...